# Out of order execution

Tags: c++, g++4.8

g++ 4.8.2 (cygwin)

The testMarkListIO() statement is executed before the testListIO() statement. Is there any reason for this?

```
bool testIO() {
   bool flag = true;

   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm * ptm;
   time ( &rawtime );
   ptm = gmtime ( &rawtime );
   stringstream pretty;
   pretty << "TestIOLog_" << ptm->tm_yday
                          << ptm->tm_hour
                          << ptm->tm_min
                          << ptm->tm_sec
                          << ".log";
   filename = pretty.str();
   flag = (testListIO())?            flag: false;
   flag = (testMarkListIO())?        flag: false;
   flag = (testDescriptorListIO())?  flag: false;
   flag = (testUserDataIO())?        flag: false;
   flag = (testInclude())?           flag: false;

   sleep(1);
   testResultOutput("Test I/O", flag);
   return flag;
}; // bool testIO()
```

Comment: If they're unrelated I suppose optimizations

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: Are these functions defined as macros or in the same source file? Do you request link-time optimization (LTO)?

Comment: Are you sure they don't just print some stuff out of order?

Comment: I am absolutely sure that I output the same title twice giving me the erroneous impression that the statement were executed out of order. I thank you all for your time and am very sorry that I wasted it. Sigh.

Comment: Never send a programmer in on a task best done by a child.

Answer (score 1):

For these statements (and the other similar ones):

```
flag = (testListIO())?            flag: false;
flag = (testMarkListIO())?        flag: false;
```

If the functions are inlined and the compiler can a tell that there are no side effects other than setting `flag`, it is free to order those statements however it sees fit as long as the value passed to `testResultOutput()` and returned from the function are are the same as what would have happened if the statements were executed strictly in order.

This is commonly known as the "as if" rule. Essentially, the compiler if free to execute things however it wants if the visible results are the same as if it executed them according to the source code order.

Answer (score 0):

Bonehead question. Sorry. The correct answer is that I made an output error. I output the wrong message. Sigh. Never trust a programmer for something a child can do.

Sorry, sorry, sorry.

art

Comment: There is something to learn, though, which is in the answer by Burr.